# meaning of "the choice fell on (somebody)"

Tags: meaning-in-context

If I say, "the choice fell on me", does it mean, "It became my responsibility to choose among the options available", or, "I was the one chosen to do something"?

The phrasal verb **to fall on**, usually means *to become someone's responsibility* ([see meaning 4](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fall+on)). Yet, **to fall** means also *to occur* ([see meaning 4](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/fall))

To give a context:

I'm telling a friend about a discussion I had with my flatmates on who should wash the dishes. And I say, "eventually the choice fell on me."
Does it mean, "I had to choose who should wash the dishes", or, "I was chosen to wash the dishes"?

Comment: Could you provide the context in which you read this?  It sounds as if someone is confused about the idiomatic expression, as I think it's normally *"the choice fell **to** me"*.  A different idiom uses *"fall **on**"*

Comment: I added a context

Comment: As @Andrew said, fell **to** would unambiguously mean that the choice was yours to make.  Based on "flatmates" I assume you're looking for BrE, but for what it's worth I *do* sometimes hear people say that a choice fell **on** them with the same intended meaning here in my part of the US -- perhaps the burden of deciding rests **on** their shoulders?

Comment: Yet, on ngram "the choice fell to me" is not even found. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+choice+fell+to+me%2Cthe+choice+fell+on+me&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20choice%20fell%20on%20me%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cthe%20choice%20fell%20on%20me%3B%2Cc0

Comment: The is precisely the problem with ngram. In English, a choice falls to this or that person or  group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The choice fell *on* me" sounds odd, as the more common idiom is "The choice fell *to* me", meaning that *I* was the one required to choose.

> Since no one else would do it, **the choice fell to me** to decide what color to paint the house -- a thankless task, since no matter which color I picked I knew someone would object.

However, I don't think it's *wrong* as much as *rare*.  I found a couple of results in older scientific journals:

> In regard to Streptomycin the committee's **choice fell on** Selman Waksman, the bacteriologist who had ascertained the effect unambiguously and also published it.
>
> For insulation, **the choice fell on** expanded rigid polyvinyl chloride, usable in sandwich form ...

From context it's clear the phrase means that whatever the choice *fell on* is what was *chosen*, not what did the *choosing*.

However, I recommend against using this idiom as it may be confusing.  When no actual *choice* is involved, you can use the more common, "it fell on me" (as in your linked definition) to do something, meaning that you were *forced* to do it by lack of other options.

> After a week I couldn't even see the kitchen counter for all the piled-up dirty dishes, and we were completely out of clean ones.  Since clearly none of my roommates would do it, it **fell on me** to do the washing-up if I didn't want to live in squalor.  But I vowed I'd make them pay for it ... somehow, someday.

Comment: What would you recommend, instead of 'the choice fell on smb', if I want to put the chosen person at the end to emphasize the identity of that person?

Answer (score 1):

From the examples provided on google

> The choice fell on a Japanese painting, lovely in colors, and depicting busy people.
>
> The choice fell on this truncated manipulation sequence for reasons of maximal reproducibility between the two investigational centers

it implies **choice fell on sth means sth was choosen**

Answer (score 1):

Just because something appears on Google does not mean that it is correct English. There are many, many things published in academic journals that are written by foreign scholars and never edited by a native English speaker. The sentence above about Japanese painting is gibberish, and the phrase "investigational centers" in the other sentence should tell you everything you need to know about the writer's level of English proficiency.