# How do you say 'the choice fell on [somebody]' in a more native-like way?

Tags: phrase-request

As I understand it, you would rarely say 'the choice fell on [somebody]'. What is a more natural way to put a chosen thing or person at the end of the sentence (as an object) in order to emphasize it?

Comment: There's nothing "un-native" about the phrase as it stands. If anything at all, *on* could become *to*. But that's minor.

Comment: Also, [see here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/201470/meaning-of-the-choice-fell-on-somebody)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- choice fell on (somebody)

This is perfectly native and used widely, although I am a non-native speaker, I have heard this a lot of times. So you can definitely use this phrasing.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be a direct active verb

> (A person) chose somebody.

This places the chosen "somebody" at the end of the sentence. Of course it does require you to mention the person doing the choosing as the subject.

Comment: That's exactly the problem with this option. I want to leave out the actor (is it 'actor'? the one who acts, performs an action; all I know it's not 'subject' or 'agent')